# Извлечь данные json в отдельные переменные

Tags: json, php

Пришли данные в виде json'a:

```
$post_data = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( "php://input" ) );
//я правильно понимаю, что
$var1 = $post_data->var1;
$var2 = $post_data->var2;
$var3 = $post_data->var3;
//можно смело заменить на
extract(get_class_vars($post_data));
```

Учитывая, что никаких левых геттеров и сеттеров нет?
Есть лучше способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а зачем ? чем вас этот массив не устраивает ? по extract в мануале что-то многовато предупреждений. Как я понял лучше всего завести массив `$allowed=array('var1','var2','var3')` и профильтровать входные данные прежде чем делать `extract`.

**Обновление**

Зачем там `extract`? В смысле чтобы превратить `$data` в локальные переменные? Сомнительное удовольствие если честно.

Вот такой кусочек yii,

```
abstract class CBaseController extends CComponent
{
 //...
 public function renderInternal($_viewFile_,$_data_=null,$_return_=false) {
  //...
  extract($_data_,EXTR_PREFIX_SAME,'data');
 }
}
```

Comment: меня даже объект ($post_data) устраивает. Но интересен принцип. Потому что именно этот метод(extract) с вероятностью 99% использует фреймворк YII, когда запускает рендер страницы, соответственно, можно ли ему скармливать переменные таким образом.